# Group cohomology question, trivial Galois action on discrete Galois module means we can say what about kernel of map

Tags: nt.number-theory, group-cohomology

Say we have a number field $K$. Let $G_K = \text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$. Let $M$ be a discrete $G_K$-module. We know that $H^1(K, M) := H^1(G_K, M)$, i.e. profinite group cohomology. For each place $v$ of $K$, let $K_v$ be the completion of $K$ at $v$; restriction to a decomposition group $G_v$ at $v$ defines a homomorphism $H^1(K, M) \to H^1(K_v, M)$. Define$$F^1(K, M) := \text{Ker}\left(H^1(K, M) \to \prod_v H^1(K_v, M)\right).$$If the $G_K$-action on $M$ is trivial, what can we say about $F^1(K, M)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the $G_K$-action on $M$ is trivial, then
$$H^1(K,M)=\mathrm{Hom}(G_K,M),$$
and by Chebotarev's density theorem
$$ F^1(K,M)=0.$$

For details see Lemma 1.1(i) of Sansuc, J.-J. Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres. J. Reine Angew. Math. 327 (1981), 12–80.

Answer (score 2):

For a refined statement, see also https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/NSW2e/index-de.html (9.1.9) (i).